# Is it an error to escape every metacharacter with PCREs and EREs?

Tags: regex, pcre

In regular expressions, some characters get the special meaning of metacharacters only if appropriately placed and remain their literal meaning otherwise. For instance, the `-` character is treated as a metacharacter only if placed within a square bracket expression `[]` and is a literal dash outside.

But personally, I like to think of metacharacters just as reserved characters and to employ the strict rule of escaping every metacharacter that needs to be literal. This saves me little bit of time that otherwise would be spent on considering where a metacharacter is located in the regex.

However, from what I know, escaping such a character is normally an error with GNU BREs. And this regular expression

```
foo\-[0-9]+
```

is considered invalid in its `\-` part by RegexBuddy. Moreover, RegexBuddy indicates the same error with GNU ERE (but not PCRE). On the other hand, `grep` on Ubuntu doesn't treat this regex as an error and it works out fine from my tests, even though `grep` was supposed to be using ERE by default.

So, putting BREs and RegexBuddy aside and considering just PCREs and EREs that are used in many present-day systems and programming languages, the question is how erroneous it might be to get used to escaping every possible metacharacter to get its literal meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only answer for PCRE here. In PCRE you can escape as much as you want and it won't make a difference. Quoting [PHP's PCRE documentation on escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> [...] if [a backslash] is followed by a non-alphanumeric character, it takes away any special meaning that character may have.

I would interprete the "**may** have" as, "it does not matter if it does not have a meaning". And I tested it with your given example and there is no problem.

---

On a general note regardless of the regex engine in use:

I would like to mention that while it seems like a good idea to escape everything always for safety, you should at least once consciously think about the readability impacts. Regular expressions tend to become hard to read anyway, and cluttering them with unnecessary backslashes does not really improve this. In particular, within character classes I would only ever escape the characters that are meta-characters inside character classes (I personally even prefer, to move them to the specific position where they don't need to be escaped, like `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`, but I can see how some people don't like that). This has a nice side-effect. You can use character classes, as a (in my opinion) more easily readable alternative for escaping characters that are meta-characters outside but not inside of character classes. So you can write `[|]` instead of `\|` or `[.]` instead of `\.`. In mono-spaced fonts this one-character character class makes a nice square, which is easily recognizable as a single element, and the important character is right in the center of it (while in `\.` the important character is displaced to the right within the "compound single character" if that makes sense). Also if it comes to escaping parentheses close to unescaped parentheses, I find the character class escaping much more readable: `(\()(\))` vs. `([(])([)])`. Of course, that again is a matter of taste. But it is something worth to think about when setting up escaping conventions for regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You're not asking about if you can "escape every metacharacter", but rather "escape every character that I'm not sure if it's a metacharacter or not."  It sounds like you just want to escape everything that isn't a letter or digit.

It's not an error in functionality, but:

- It makes the code harder to read.  The fewer characters, the better.
- It makes the programmer who comes after you wonder why you are escaping characters unnecessarily and spend time trying to figure out what is different about your code and what problem you're trying to get around.
- When that programmer finally figures out that you're just escaping non-metacharacter characters for the heck of it, she's going to think you're an incompetent programmer.

Learn your tools, learn to use them properly, and don't use voodoo tricks to get around your lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about POSIX regexes or PCRE, but in Perl every backslashed non-word character is guaranteed to match itself. See [`perldoc -f quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) for details.